# Application not running on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I'm trying to set up petclinic spring boot app on aws ec2 machine but the application fails to start with the below error:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/petclinic] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/petclinic]]]
```

I checked in `logs/catalina.out` and this is below:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Cat
alina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/petclinic]]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
07-Jan-2020 13:51:38.020 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/web
apps/petclinic.war] has finished in [5,615] ms
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.41
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.966 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 4 2019 09:17:16 UTC
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.41.0
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.14.138-89.102.amzn1.x86_64
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8
.b10.38.amzn1.x86_64/jre
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.971 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_171-b10
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
07-Jan-2020 13:51:39.975 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat
/conf/logging.properties
```

How can I get the application to start successfully?

Im unable to attach complete log. I suspect this could be related to versions conflict.

This the version info where  app is running fine :
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.50
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.50
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.50
Server built:   Dec 7 2019 19:19:46 UTC
Server number:  8.5.50.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.18.0-147.3.1.el8_1.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    11.0.5+10-LTS
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

But my current version is like below:
sh: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/bin/version.sh: No such file or directory
[root@ip-172-31-11-16 logs]# sh /opt/tomcat/bin/version.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.41
Server built:   May 4 2019 09:17:16 UTC
Server number:  8.5.41.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.14.138-89.102.amzn1.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_171-b10
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Comment: There is nothing logged before the first line with `java.lang.IllegalStateException`?

Comment: Is this the complete logs?

Comment: Im unable to attach complete log. I suspect this could be related to versions conflict. Plz check above in question with versions im running.